# Parametric integral convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Provided that $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$, is the following integral

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{x^{\beta-\alpha-1} \exp\left(-\beta x - \frac{\alpha}{x} \right) dx} $$

convergent?

I know that the integrand is continuous on $]0,+\infty[$ and is equivalent to $x^{\beta-\alpha-1} \exp(-\beta x)$ near $x=+\infty$ and $x^{\beta-\alpha-1} \exp(-\frac{\alpha}{x})$ near $x=0$. So this should be enough to confirm the convergence?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough.

Comment: here is a solution created by Mathematica $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[2 \alpha
   ^{\frac{\beta -\alpha }{2}} (-\beta )^{\frac{\alpha
   -\beta }{2}} K_{\alpha -\beta }\left(2 \sqrt{\alpha
   } \sqrt{-\beta }\right),\Re(\beta )<0\land
   \Re(\alpha )>0\right]$$